# Google Cloud Sites gives "504 Gateway Error" 2 hours after installation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a issue with Google Cloud

Recently a "504 Gateway" error occurred. Although I set up a new Snapshot 2 hours after my site is crashing again.

http://prntscr.com/nfxetm

Dasboard doesn't seem to have any error message.

http://zetacreativo.com my current website host by google cloud.

In total, the fifth penny from the snapshot backup. I don't use any malware just automatic plugins.. Still 2 hours after my site is crashing again.